# Laravel : Response Headers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, http-headers

I am looking into a Laravel Project. Its a big one.

I need to set a response header for OPTIONS request type and I did come across many files and tried stuffs but could not achieve it.

Any pointers? About where I should look into.

Comment: You can use CORS package like this https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Answer (score 0):

You can add these line on  routes.php Laravel 5.2

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization');
```

You can also set the headers in the web.config file and now CORS would work without hacking the routes.php file.

```
 <customHeaders>
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
 </customHeaders>
```

Comment: web.config is not there. And I am getting this status : 406 and statusText : "Not Acceptable"